# DevOps Pipeline Variables cannot be compared

Tags: variables, compare, devops, pipeline, external

I have a question to DevOps Pipelines.

I have created a Pipeline and during this creation I add a variable with this values “ Name: RESIDENCE ; value: ISS“. So this Value is defined outside from any script.
[Pipeline Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMlFQ.png)

Inside the .yml file I use this code:

```
    variables:
    - name: shuttle
      value: Columbia
    - name: pipe_var
      value: $(RESIDENCE)    
    - name: location
      ${{ if eq(variables.pipe_var, 'ISS') }}:
        value: pretty_cool
      ${{ if eq(variables.pipe_var, 'MIR') }}:
        value: not_possible

    steps:
    - script: |
        echo space shuttle is: $(shuttle)
        echo     residence is: $(pipe_var)
        echo   place to be is: $(location)
```

But The Pipeline output is only showing:

```
space shuttel is: Columbia
    resicende is: ISS
  place to be is:
```

So as it can be seen in the line “resicende is: ISS “ the value from the outside variable “RESIDENCE” is shown correct.  To show this value I use the detour over the variable “pipe_var”. But when I try to compare this variable value with the “if equal” lines then I get no results.

What I’m doing wrong? Is there a special way to compare string values in a pipeline?

It would be nice if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with both variables and parameters, if you output them they display the correct string but when you compare a string with the value of the parameter or variable its always false. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!